# 403 Forbidden running MVC3 from VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, firefox, iis-7

I've recently had a name change to my PC and rebooted.  Before this change, I could run my MVC3 project from VS2010 using IIS 7.  After the name change I getting:

Http Error 403 Forbidden Version Information: ASP.NET Development Server 10.0.0.0

I realise this could be a number of things so I'll try, in detail, to describe what's going on.

**IIS**
My IIS reverted back to v6 so I loaded 7 and set my DefaultAppPool to use .NET v4.0.
Security has all permissions for my account.
Request Filtering has 'Allow unlisted file name extensions checked (another answer on SO)

I'm using FireFox 24.0

VS2010 hasn't changed as far as I'm aware.

I'm not very familiar with IIS which, seems to me, is my problem so please bear this in mind if you decide to help.  I'll gladly provide more information if needed.

thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer - I changed windows authentication password which wasn't updated in firefox.  I changed the password to be in sync and it solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually have IIS7 installed or are you using IIS Express or Cassini?

I'm pretty sure that you'll be able to get things going again if you use the [aspnet_regiis](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) command.

Navigate to your .Net folder and run the following command `aspnet_regiis -i`

Comment: I navigated to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 in command prompt and ran asp_net regiis -i .  The error was that I don't have admin permissions to run this tool.  Yet, when I see my account in User Accounts, I am the administer with complete rights.  Why am I getting this error?

Comment: OK, so I chose 'Run as Administrator' and ran aspnet_regiis -i which ran ok.  But I'm still getting 403 Forbidden when I run my solution.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the answer but rather a different question.  The problem wasn't IIS, the problem is with FireFox.  I changed the default browser to Chrome and my app runs as it should.

Comment: Glad to see you figured it out.